# Matlab save a figure in EPS format

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, eps

I have a lot of .fig figures, and after I got the good apparence, I save as (directly from hand) .eps file. But the figure changes : the initial font turn to corrier new, and text overwrites boxes. Is there a better way to correct this ?

Comment: try `export_fig`. MATLAB is notoriously bad for saving figures properly

Comment: See [this contribution](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig).